# Visual Studio 2010 + ReSharper Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've installed ReSharper 5 on two installations of Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  In both cases, ReSharper claims it has installed successfully - but Visual Studio doesn't recognize the extension.  It doesn't show up in the Extensions Manager, doesn't appear in Help - About - Installed products, and can't be found anywhere else in the environment.

I've tried install / uninstall of both Visual Studio and ReSharper, computer restarts, etc.  Both machines have Visual Studio 2008 and ReSharper 5 works fine in these IDEs, and both machines are running Windows 7.

I've found other people online with this issue, but no solutions.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you contact JetBrains/ReSharper support.

Comment: I have the ReSharper 30-day trial, and Visual Studio 2010 from Microsoft DreamSpark.

Comment: Which VS version do you get via DreamSpark? If it's the Express-Edition, that one doesn't support extentions.

Comment: It's the Professional version.

Comment: Joel, it doesn't matter whether you have resharper license or trial - JetBrains will welcome any feedback about Resharper problems. Unfortunately, there is a long holidays in Russia atm, so you could experience delays with response =(

Answer (score 8):

Check that ReSharper is enabled in `Tools->Options->ReSharper`. Suspend and unsuspend it, in case that helps (I've heard that work before). Note that ReSharper will notice if more than one computer on a given network is running the same license, and disable all but one of the instances that are running. Check that hasn't happened to you.

Answer (score 2):

Run `devenv /resetskippkgs`, solved my issues in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by just copying the JetBrains folder from other version of Visual Studio:

This is visual studio 2010 folder for extensions:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\

This is visual studio 2012 folder for extensions:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\

I just copied from 2012 folder the 'JetBrains' and pasted to the 2010 extensions folder.